# How to place and space captions of subfigures

Tags: captions, subfloats, subcaption, subfig

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[journal,twocolumn,10pt]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[t]
\centering
\subfigure[Line]{\centering
  $E= \begin{bmatrix}
      0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
      1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
      0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
      0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    \end{bmatrix}$}
\subfigure[Square]{\centering
  $E= \begin{bmatrix}
      0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
      1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
      0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
      1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    \end{bmatrix}$}
\subfigure[Full]{\centering
  $E= \begin{bmatrix}
      0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
      1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
      1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
      1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
    \end{bmatrix}$}
\subfigure[Star]{\centering
  $E= \begin{bmatrix}
      0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
      1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
      1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
      1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    \end{bmatrix}$}
\caption{Adjacency matrices for network graphs}
\label{EMATRICES}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

which results in this figure:

[image]

I would like to know if there is any form to center the captions and subcaptions and give some space between the subcaptions and the matrices.

Regards

Comment: For the vertical space: `\setlength{\subfigcapskip}{0.3cm}`. But are you sure that a figure is the best environment to show matrices?

Comment: @samcarter Thanks. I do not use an array of math equations because I would like to place labels and \ref labels I could use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your subcaptions are centered, they are just not centered with the matrices, because there is also *E =* in front.

The subfigures you had are not really figures, that is why the subcaptions appear so close to them. They could be converted to figures with `TikZ`.

The positioning of the caption can be customized with package `caption`.

Here is code

```latex
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[t]
\centering
\captionsetup{justification=centering}
\resizebox {0.8 \columnwidth}{!}{
\subfigure[Line]{\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) node {$E = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\subfigure[Square]{\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) node {$E = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
}
\resizebox {0.8 \columnwidth}{!}{
\subfigure[Full]{\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) node {$E = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\subfigure[Star]{\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) node {$E = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
}
\caption{Adjacency matrices for network graphs}
\label{EMATRICES}
\end{figure}
```

Here is how it looks like

> [image: subfloat]

Comment: thanks. How could I set the width of the subfigures to fill for example `0.8\columnwidth`?.

Comment: @user1993416 You could use `\resizebox`, please see the updated code in the answer.